# QList as a property in qt designer custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

i have defined a custom widget, basically adding to QLabel. The simple (Qstring and enum ) properties are ok and appear in my QT designer.

I am now trying to add a property which is a list.

So I declare my property as :

```
 Q_PROPERTY(QList<int> points READ getpoints )
```

and I have my private variable `QList<int> m_points;`

Still, I cannot see my points property in QT designer propriety editor. And, I don't know what went wrong.

I've tried to add the DESIGNABLE flag but it does nothing.

Any clue ?

Comment: Do you have a method "QList<int> getpoints()" ?

Comment: yep. It returns the private variable.

Comment: Probably because the QVariant type system does not wrap arbitrary lists. You'd need to wrap the list in a typedef at least, and declare it as a new streamable metatype. Look in QVariant and QDataStream for what's to be done.

Comment: @Kuba Ober Is typedef really necessary? I think QVariant should work fine with this type once it's declared properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact I forgot the WRITE part in the property.

Adding the set method and the Write in the Q_PROPERTY did the trick.